# Can't get second level routes working in express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm sorry I'm reasonably new to node. I've been stuck on this for a couple hours.

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(templatesPath + 'index.html'));
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(templatesPath + 'index.html'));
});
```

index.html is an Angular application. I have the first level of routes working fine using Angular's HTML5 routes eg. "http://lh:3000/staff" or "http://lh:3000"

but if I add another level or route parameters, e.g. "http://lh:3000/staff/" or "http://lh:3000/staff/test" Express seems to ignore express.static and instead uses the get wildcard to turn all my files into index.html so my page breaks.

**Thanks for your help answerers**

In secondary routes, it was loading assets referenced in index.html, relative to the secondary route. My temp solution is to add:
app.use('/files/',express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
but I realise now it is better to change my solution.

Answer (score 1):

are `staff/test`, static assets sitting inside your assets folder? 
If they are static assets, there must be a file in the path staff/test inside your assets folder.

if they are not static assets and they are dynamic content, consider using `express.router`,make a router for `staff` and add it as,

```
var staff = express.Router();
staff.use('/staff', staff)

//this is route handler for /staff/test
staff.post('/test', function(req, res, next){
  res.json(some-json-content)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of Routers. I need to sleep now but I'll look into it tomorrow and post my answer when I come up with it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
app.get('*/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(templatesPath + 'index.html'));
});
```